# How to call function from an object containing the function pointer from another object?

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

Let's make it clear..

```
enum toto {F1, F2, F3};

typedef void A::*func();
class A
{
  void f1();
  void f2();
  void f3();
};

class B
{
  func _f;
  int _x;
  int _y;
  B(func f, int x, int y) : _f(f), _x(x), _y(y)
};

class C
{
  A *a;
  std::map<toto, B *> _map;
  _map[F1] = new B(&A::f1, 42, 42);
  _map[F2] = new B(&A::f2, 12, 21);
  _map[F3] = new B(&A::f3, 0, 0);
  toto t;
  void app()
  {
    std::map<toto, B *>::iterator it = _map.find(t);
    B *tmp = it->second;
    /* HERE IS MY PROBLEM: HOW CAN I CALL THE FUNCTION F1, F2 OR F3 FROM 
       A VIA B in C ? */
    *(tmp->_f)(); // NOT WORKING 
  }
};
```

At compilation, I get this error message:

> error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘tmp->B::_f (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* tmp->B::_f) (...)’

Comment: The syntax to call a pointer to member would be `(ptr->*_f)()`. However, why do you think you can call a function of `A` on and object of type `B`? Did you mean `B` to be derived from `A`?

Comment: Well, `A::f1` etc are nonstatic member functions of `A`, so you need an `A` object to call them on. Where is that?

Comment: @user3827622 `(a->*(tmp->_f))();`